# Converting a derived list, obtained via reflection, into a list of its base class

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, system.reflection

How can I do the below? Or is there a better way I should be doing this?

Perhaps a more concrete way of imagining it, is I want to have a single UI page that accepts a list of Mammals and then obtains the public properties of that Mammal-derived class via reflection to do Get/Set Value.

The members of the list are guaranteed to be all of the same type. I guess I could convert it to a DataTable or something, but I'm working with existing sets of classes here.
These strongly-typed lists are already coming from established classes, so I can't get use List< Mammal > at their origin.
I'm programatically generating a UI form from the object properties. I don't want to have to make a MonkeyForm, DogForm, GiraffeForm, CowForm. I just want to make a MammalForm and pass it any of the lists.

```
class Monkey : Mammal {};
class Dog : Mammal {};

class Cage
{
    [AnimalCollection(true)]
    List<Monkey> Monkeys;
};

class Kennel
{
    [AnimalCollection(true)]
    List<Dog> Dogs;
};

System.Reflection.PropertyInfo prop = myCageInstance.GetAnimalCollectionViaAttribute();
// We have the PropertyInfo now of our List<Monkey>.
// Convert it to List<Mammal> so we can pass it to our UI page
```

Comment: You are doing it wrong if you need to do derived class get/sets. What behavior isn't common that you need to avoid polymorphism?

Comment: Think of a form that displays fields for entry from an object's properties.
The Dog and Monkey both have different properties. I've updated the original question a bit. A list is guaranteed to be of all the same type.

Comment: I don't think you understand: *The fact that a simple List<Mammal> is not enough is a code-smell*. Using reflection is a **last resort**, when you are so far in the weeds you just need a way out. I'm curious why are you are in the weeds; so I can suggest a way out. BTW `IEnumerable` is covariant; so if you cast to that the base/derived relationship will work.

Comment: For the form that procedurally generates fields for entry, I don't want to make a CowForm, DogForm, MonkeyForm, GiraffeForm. I just want a MammalForm where I can pass it any list of Mammals and it'll accept it (in case I add more mammals in the future).

Comment: Then, ill-advised as it may be; can you just take an `IEnumerable<Mammal>` instead of `List`? You may even be able to get away with `IList`

Comment: @BradleyDotNET `IList` not going to work - there is no `out`: `interface IList<T>` unlike `interface IEnumerable<out T>` so you can't cast `IList<derived>` to `IList<base>`. (which is somewhat expected as you can both `Add` and `Get` with `IList`)